# Graph plotting in Excel from C++ application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, excel

My C++ application generates a .csv file containing 10000 floats. 
Now the requirement is that there should be a graph in the same file depicting those floats.

I understand that csv files cannot have graphs. So I have to switch to Excel

Assuming I can write data into columns in excel sheet can anybody tell me if  there is any function that I can call in my C++ program which will plot the data in excel sheet?

I have seen some solutions based on Python, but I am exploring if it is possible from C++ only.

Comment: Did you check if there are C# connectors?

My personal opinion would be to use Python and matplotlib, but ...

Comment: Maybe silly, but can you call a vba function from your c++ program? I don't know of a c++ way to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+Excel+OLE

The MSDN documentation is also often useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library [SimpleXlsxWriter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplexlsx/). It is possible to plot basic graphs on the separate sheet in the excel book. There are also some examples of using on the wiki page of the project

The library provides no external dependencies

Answer (score 0):

This might be of use, especially the last chapter:

[www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~ahazel/EXCEL_C++.pdf](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~ahazel/EXCEL_C++.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

CSV is a graph format.
It stands for Comma Separated Value.
You can load this file into Excel.
 It will also import into SQL, MYSQL use (PHPMyadmin for this).
SQL stands for Structured Query Language. MYSQL is web based.
Best wishes to you.
http://www.whatisacnc.com